# Windows Drive Letter Information?

Tags: windows

Where is the information about assigned windows drive letters stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the Registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
```

More information in the [**Microsoft Knowledge Base**](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=223188).